# React Native : Unable to locate audio file after download

Tags: react-native, audio

I'm using react-native-simple-download-manager to download audio files into the app's download folder :

```
headers = {
              Authorization: "Téléchargement"
            };

            config = {
              downloadTitle: `${audio.Title}`,
              downloadDescription: "Téléchargement",
              saveAsName: audio.Title +'.mp3',
              allowedInRoaming: true,
              allowedInMetered: true,
              showInDownloads: true,
              external: false, //when false basically means use the default Download path (version ^1.3)
            };
            downloadManager
              .download((url = audio.FileUrl), (headers = headers), (config = config))
              .then(response => {
                saveData(audio);
              })
              .catch(err => {
                           if(index > -1) {
                  global.downloadingSongId.splice(index,1);
                }
              });
```

I can find the downloaded audio files on the phone, but the player can't read the audio given by the
 following path : dirs.DocumentDir + '/Download/' + audio.Title + '.mp3'

And when I use RNFetchBlob to check if the path exists it always return false :

```
let path = dirs.DocumentDir + '/' + audio.Title + '.mp3';
RNFetchBlob.fs.exists(path);
```

I really appreciate if anyone could help!